# h2 database select query slow

Tags: select, jdbc, h2, timing

I use an h2 database file in my Java app.  The database is relatively small, 5M, on a SSD.  The biggest table is about 25000 rows (25 columns).  A simple select query on this table takes around 1.3 seconds.  It seems very slow.  The table has a primary key on ID.  Here is the test code:

```
    long tic = System.nanoTime();
    final String sqlCmd = "select * from Transactions order by ID";
    //final String sqlCmd = "select ID from TRANSACTIONS order by ID";
    try (Statement statement = mConnection.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlCmd)) {

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        mLogger.error("SQLException " + e.getSQLState(), e);
    }
    long toc = System.nanoTime();
    System.err.println("transactionTimingTest: " + (toc-tic)/1e6);
```

Repeating the same select query runs reasonably faster, about 0.2 seconds.  Is there any way to improve the timing of the first run of the select query on the table?

Comment: You should clarify, what you try to achieve. Your code requires to sort all the data from the table (`select *`) by `ID` (which is the first time slower due to disc access). After this you through it away as you do not fetch the result set. So the questions are; do you need to process *all rows*, do you need the *order by ID*, do you need *all columns* to be selected? And if so, *why don't you fetch the result set*?

Comment: My objective is to cut down the time for the first select query.  I do need to process every single row from the resultset.  The code I posted was for timing test.  I understand the first time would be a bit slower due to the disk access. But it shouldn't take that much time to read a 5M file.  If I time the dd command, it takes less than 0.05 second to read the whole 5M file.

Comment: In the full code, each row is processed and a transaction object is created and added to a list. All these process cost around 0.6 s.

Comment: Also, with or without the 'order by ID' clause makes no difference in terms of timing.

Comment: Your last comment I'd interpret that you basically observes a delay for getting the connection and making the `executeQuery` work. If so you'll see similar timing using `select * from EmptyTable`. Good luck and thanks for explanation!

Comment: @MarmiteBomber The connection was opened and a number of other queries was performed on other tables in this database.  The 1.3 s is purely for executing the select query on this particular table.  In fact, I tried the timing code with a smaller table and it took just a few micro seconds.

Comment: correction: a few milliseconds instead of a few microseconds.

Comment: What's your H2 version and jdbc connection? And can you show the table structure?

Comment: @auntyellow I tried h2 1.4.196,197,199. all pretty much the same.  jdbc was from openjdk 11.0.9.1.  The columns are (in order)
integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
integer NOT NULL
date NOT NULL
date
decimal(20,4)
varchar(16) not null
integer
integer
varchar(255) not null
varchar (16) not null
varchar (64) not null
boolean
integer
integer
varchar(16)
integer
decimal(20,8)
decimal(20,8)
decimal(20,8)
varchar(40)
decimal(20,4)
decimal(20,4)
decimal(20,4)
integer
integer
varchar(256) not null

Comment: jdbc connection? such as `jdbc:h2:/var/lib/h2/test;mode=postgresql;database_to_lower=true;access_mode_data=r;lazy_query_execution=1`

Comment: "jdbc:h2:~/fubar;CIPHER=AES;IFEXISTS=TRUE;"

Comment: does `CIPHER=AES` affect speed?

Comment: @auntyellow  I didn't test it without the CIPHER=AES.  First I definitely need the db to be encrypted.  Second, it takes quite a bit more effort to recreate the database without AES.  I'll put on my todo list to check this out.